# Can't import numpy when venv is activated with activate_this

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

When I activate my venv normally, things work fine.

However, when I use the activate_this.py library to activate internally to my python script, I get:

```
>>> this_file='win\\CYAN\Scripts\\activate_this.py'
>>> exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Dropbox (CEP)\venvs\win\CYAN\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
```

[LOTS of stuff about standard causes of this problem deleted ending with]

```
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

In both cases I'm using the same python: C:\Python37\python.exe which is 64b (I ran virtualenv with -p python so the virtualenv is just a copy of that...)

ETA: 
I see that there are some references from 2015 about numpy not being 64b... I assume that that's dealt with by now, because I've seen no reference to it since then... if I'm wrong, that would be good to know...

Added data: This appears to be something set up weirdly on MY computer.. when I try this on someone elses computer (set up supposedly the same way...) it works fine... Even across dropbox...

This probably has to do with the warnings I got when doing the pip install -r requirements.txt, but I'm not getting anymore so maybe there was a problem in the requirements.txt...

Comment: Do you have numpy installed? Is it listed in `pip freeze` output when run inside virtualenv.

Comment: yes. When I activate with the activate script, and run python I can import numpy fine.